# Create a transparent UIView with some information in it

Tags: ios, uiview

In my app I take a picture then I add on this picture weather forecast and position with some UILabels and some UIImageviews. For now I'm getting picture like this:

[image]

But I will create something like the following picture:

[image]

Does anyone ions how to do a stuff like the second picture?
In other word I've to create a transparent section in which I will show the weather forecast, the position and the date.
I hope you can help me

Comment: I just want to know how to create a transparent UIView in which I will put some information. For now I did similar to the first picture the objective it's to do a stuff similar to the second picture. i hope you understand what I mean

Comment: @gran33: his question is quite clear and provides enough information. You didn't read it? Did you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create this hierarchy to create view.Set Alpha as you want.[image]

Comment: Thank you! Now I can do it without difficult :)

Answer (score 0):

Wherever u set the view, just add this for example:

```
yourView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
yourView.alpha = 0.5;
```

U can change the background color to whatever u want...

Notice! 
The `alpha` will effect also the `subviews` of `yourView`.

So u can play with it, with some views with transparent backgrounds above `yourView`..

Good Luck!

Comment: Doesn't work as it will affect all subviews's alpha too.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to set a `backgroundColor` with transparency (not translucency), you assign background color like this:

```
yourView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor darkGrayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5f];
```

If this is inside `UIImagePickerController`, you might want to check out the [cameraOverlayView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/cameraOverlayView) property of UIImagePickerController`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try changing the background colour of the view. For example make it black and add an alpha value.

**For Example:**

```
[yourview setBackgroungColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:<#(CGFloat)#> green:<#(CGFloat)#> blue:<#(CGFloat)#> alpha:<#(CGFloat)#>]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the view layer for achieving this kinda effect in your view controller like i would do if i have to

[image]